# incompatible types to type 'Ev' from type 'int' at line 50

Tags: c, linux

Scheduler.c 
I am making scheduling program for class and I am stuck with this error. It says incompatible  types to type  'Ev' from type  'int'. I am confused to what this could mean.

```
int main()
{
 Ev *event; 
    int numEvents=0;
    int option;
    int x;
    int y;

    char menu[]="1 - Insert a new event\n2 - Display all events\n3 - Now?\n4 - Delete expired\n0 - Exit\nPlease select an option: ";

    event = malloc(sizeof(Ev) *numEvents);
    CopynumEvents(&numEvents);
    for (y=0; y<numEvents; y++)
    {
        event = realloc(event, sizeof(Ev) * (y + 1));



     **MY ERROR SEEMS TO BE AROUND THIS AREA**

        event[y]=CopyfromFile(numEvents,y);   
   }

    option = MenuOption(menu); 
    while(1)
    {
        switch(option)
        {
            case(1):           

                event = realloc(event, sizeof(Ev) * (numEvents + 1));
                numEvents++;
                event[numEvents - 1]=InsertEvent();            
                ArrangeEvents(event,numEvents);
                CopytoFile(numEvents, event);              
                option = MenuOption(menu);             
                break;

            case(2):

                if (numEvents!=0)
                {
                    for (x=0;  x<numEvents;  x++)
                    {                      
                        DisplayEvent(event[x]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("No event in scheduler\n");
                }
                option = MenuOption(menu);             
                break;

            case(3):

                ActiveEvents(event, numEvents);
                option = MenuOption(menu);
                break;

            case(4):

                DeleteExpired(event, &numEvents);
                CopytoFile(numEvents, event);
                option = MenuOption(menu);
                break;

            case(0):

                free(event);
                exit(1);       
                break; 

        }
    }          
}

int MenuOption(char *prompt)
{
    char buffer[100];
    int option;

    do
    {
        printf("%s", prompt);

        /* Get a line of up to 100 characters */
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

        /* Remove any \n we may have input */
        if(strlen(buffer) > 0)
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';

        sscanf(buffer, "%d", &option);

    }while(option!=1 && option!=2 && option!=3 && option!=4 && option!=0);

    return option;
}

struct Event InsertEvent()
{
    struct Event E1;

    printf("What is the event: ");          
    InputEventname(E1.name, sizeof(E1.name));   
    E1.date = InputDate("Event date: ");
    E1.start = InputTime("Start time: ",E1.date);
    do
    {
    E1.end = InputTime("End time: ",E1.date);
    }while(E1.end<=E1.start);

    return E1;
}

void InputEventname(char *str, int max)
{
    char buffer[100];

    /* Get a line of up to 100 characters */
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    /* Remove any \n we may have input */
    if(strlen(buffer) > 0)
        buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';

    /* Copy up to max characters to our string */
    strncpy(str, buffer, max);
    str[max-1] = '\0';
}


time_t InputTime(char *prompt, time_t date)
{
    char buffer[100];
    char *result;
    struct tm time;

    time = *localtime(&date);

    do
    {
        printf("%s", prompt);

        /* Get a line of up to 100 characters */
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

        /* Remove any \n we may have input */
        if(strlen(buffer) > 0)
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';

        result = strptime(buffer, "%I:%M%p", &time);

    } while(result == NULL);

    return mktime(&time);
}


time_t InputDate(char *prompt)
{
    char buffer[100];
    char *result;
    struct tm date;

    do
    {
        printf("%s", prompt);

        /* Get a line of up to 100 characters */
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

        /* Remove any \n we may have input */
        if(strlen(buffer) > 0)
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';

        result = strptime(buffer, "%m/%d/%Y", &date);

    } while(result == NULL);

    /* Convert to time_t format */
    date.tm_min = 0;
    date.tm_hour = 0;
    date.tm_sec = 0;   
    date.tm_isdst = 1;

    return mktime(&date);
}
```

here is my header.  I believe I have done this part right

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define __USE_XOPEN
#include <time.h>


#include "scheduler.h"

/*

 * This is my scheduling program!!
 */


/* Our possible scheduling states */
#define NewEvent 1
#define AllEvents 2
#define Now 3
#define Expired 4
#define Exit 0




#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H

typedef struct Event
{    
   char name[50];      
    time_t date;  
   time_t start;    
   time_t end;  
int y;
}Ev;

int MenuOption(char *prompt);
struct Event InsertEvent();
void InputEventname(char *str, int max);
time_t InputDate(char *prompt);
time_t InputTime(char *prompt, time_t date);
void DisplayEvent(Ev event);


#endif
```

Comment: `CopyfromFile` ? can we look into it ?

Comment: It means you're trying to set a variable of type Ev to an int variable. Chances are your CopyFromFile method returns an int, not an Ev, so `event[y]=CopyfromFile(numEvents,y);` is attempting to set event[y] (which should be of type "Ev") to a value of type "int"

Comment: Line 50 is where the error is

Comment: do `#include <stdlib.h>`, and show the `CopyfromFile` function

Answer (score 0):

The macro `__USE_XOPEN` is an internal name; it shouldn't be set by you.  You should use `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or something similar (500, 600, or 700).  Further, it should be set before *any* POSIX header is included.  The standard C headers are also POSIX headers.

You should give the exact error message (except for the pathname of the file(s) if they're longer than about 20 characters; chop them down to the basename) in the question.  A key component of the information is the line number; you should identify that line in the file unless it is line 1 (maybe up to line 10, but don't omit *any* lines if you don't mark the line with the error).

Since you say the compiler warns about:

```
incompatible types to type 'Ev' from type 'int'
```

you could have a problem with `malloc()` and `realloc()` not being declared, or it could be `CopyfromFile()` that is not declared.  If you don't declare a function before it is used, the C compiler will assume it returns an `int` — that was correct for C89 and pre-standard C.  Strictly, for C99 or C11, the compiler should reject the compilation, but most don't unless you tell them to do so.

If you're compiling with GCC, use stringent warning options — especially to warn you about missing prototypes.  I use:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror …
```

You might use `-Wold-style-declaration` too, or instead, and some (older) versions of GCC may not support the `-Wold-style-*` options.  If your code compiles cleanly with those options, it avoids an awful lot of problems.